# PhoneGap (1.9): How to use Filesystem to delete content of a Folder?

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems, sencha-touch

I'm working with Sencha Touch 2.0 and PhoneGap 1.9 to create an Android Application. I'm already saving all images (by taking a camera-shot) on the SD-Card using the Filesystem-access provided by PhoneGap.

Now I also wanna be able to delete the whole content of the Folder on the SD-Card whenever the user uninstalls the app.

In the API Doc I couldnt find a fitting delete operation, so I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use [DirectoryEntry.removeRecursively](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry_removerecursively).